# PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtBoundSignal' objects> returned a result with an error set -

Tags: python, authentication, logging, pyqt5

```
def format(self, record: logging.LogRecord) -> str:
    record_clone = copy.copy(record)
    record_clone.__dict__.update(self._colordict)
    if record_clone.levelname in self._log_colors:
        color = self._log_colors[record_clone.levelname]
        color_str = self._colordict[color]
        record_clone.log_color = color_str  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
    else:
        record_clone.log_color = ''  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
    for field in ['msg', 'filename', 'funcName', 'levelname', 'module',
                  'name', 'pathname', 'processName', 'threadName']:
        data = str(getattr(record_clone, field))
        setattr(record_clone, field, pyhtml.escape(data))
    msg = super().format(record_clone)
    if not msg.endswith(self._colordict['reset']):
        msg += self._colordict['reset']
    return msg 

def write(self, msg):
    if not self.signalsBlocked():
        self.sig_message_written.emit(msg)`

def emit(self, record):
    record_formatted = self.format(record)

    # Use static method from Mensenger class to emit the log message
    if record_formatted:
        Mensenger.stdout().write(record_formatted)
        #print("")
    return super().emit(str(record))
```

*I am using the Python log system and when the (self.sig_message_written.emit(msg)) signal is emit generates the error shown below.*

*Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/danilo/miniconda3/envs/ciermag-develop/lib/python3.8/logging/init.py", line 954, in handle self.emit(record) File "/home/danilo/ciermag-system-develop/packages/pymr/pymr/init.py", line 205, in emit Messenger.stdout().write(record_formatted) File "/home/danilo/ciermag-system-develop/packages/pymr/pymr/init.py", line 148, in write self.sig_message_written.emit(msg) SystemError: <method 'emit' of 'PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtBoundSignal' objects> returned a result with an error set*

Comment: For example: if I put "test" in place of record_formatted error will not occur. But record_formatted's already the "str" type.

Comment: Add details to the question, not to comments. Also, as already requested, provide a [mre].

Comment: It's a question and already have the details there. I am using the python 8 logs system and this error is reproduced.

Comment: Sorry but that is *not* a MRE: for instance, we don't know to what class (and inheritance) those methods belong, nor how is that class created and used. And, as said, the details (like those you wrote in the comment above) *must* be in the question body, you must also explain ***how*** you're "using the python log system". Please carefully follow the [tour], read [ask] and review the [checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).

Comment: Thanks, I'll review the question here.